# the type of the return value in c# can not match the type in ActionScript

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a flash application(by AS3) and a server application(by c#). I use the AMF to send and get  messages between them. But now I have a problem that I cannot return a value of Object type(which containes another object value that containes two List value) to the ActionSript.

this is the C# program

```
public AMFAddressBookResult SyncAddressBook(AMFLogin loginArgs, AMFAddressBook addressBook)
{
    var result = new AMFAddressBookResult(API_ID);

    AMFReceiver[] receivers = null;
    this.GetReceivers(accessKey, out receivers))

    AMFGroup[] groups = null;
    this.GetGroups(accessKey, out groups))

    result.ResultCode = AMFAddressBookResult.Success;
    return result; // here I cannot return because the type doesnot match
}
```

here are the definitions of each class

```
public class AMFAddressBookResult : AMFResult
{
    public AMFAddressBookResult()
        : this(0)
    {
        this.AddressBook = new AMFAddressBook();
    }

    public AMFAddressBookResult(int apiID)
        : base(apiID)
    {
        this.AddressBook = new AMFAddressBook();
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "addressBook")]
    public AMFAddressBook AddressBook
    { get; set; }

    //this one cannot work too
    //private AMFAddressBook m_AddressBook;
    //[DataMember(Name = "addressBook")]
    //public AMFAddressBook AddressBook
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return m_AddressBook;
    //    }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        m_AddressBook = new AMFAddressBook();
    //    }
    //}

}

public class AMFAddressBook
{
    public AMFAddressBook()
    {
        this.m_Receivers = new List<AMFReceiver>();
        this.m_Groups = new List<AMFGroup>();
    }

    private List<AMFReceiver> m_Receivers;
    [DataMember(Name = "receiverList")]
    public AMFReceiver[] Receivers
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Receivers.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            m_Receivers = new List<AMFReceiver>(value);
        }
    }
    private List<AMFGroup> m_Groups;
    [DataMember(Name = "groupList")]
    public AMFGroup[] Groups
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Groups.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            m_Groups = new List<AMFGroup>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

and in the ActionScript , the above method should return to this method which accept an object type:

```
private function onCallSyncAddressBook( result:Object ):void
```

of course I have definited each class which matches the c# class like AMFAddressBook,AMFAddressBookResult, AMFGroup,AMFReceiver....in ActionScript

I want to know why the c# method cannot return to ActionScript and if it's because the type mis-matched.

Comment: Are your types registered, as in: `flash.net.registerClassAlias("com.example.eg", ExampleClass);`

Comment: no,I think there is no types registered.to tell the truth , i know little about AS3, it is wretten by another people.Would you please tell me how to register the type?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.amf.server.html